# Dynamic CSP (Content Security Policy) connect-src in Angular

Tags: html, angular, meta-tags, meta, content-security-policy

I defined the CSP within meta tags in my Angulars project `index.html` file

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
        content="default-src 'self';
                 connect-src 'self' https://baseurl1/ https://baseurl2/ https://baseurl3/;
                 img-src 'self' data: http://baseurl/;
                 frame-src 'self' blob:;
                 media-src 'self' https://baseurl/;
                 script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://baseurl/;
                 style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

My issue is, that I want to whitelist exactly one more `connect-src` dynamically based on a users choice within the application. How to do that since `index.html` is a static page?

The url is called from a http service, which reaches out to a standard server interface (different providers). The user can choose his provider, as a result the url changes. There is no known set of possible urls. It would be also fine if I can somehow CSP-ignore all requests which are sent by this service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try by making use of Meta component for updating CSP dynamically.

It will be like below which might help you.

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

    let i  = 0;
    let tim = setInterval(() => {

        let tag = this.meta.getTag('http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy');

        if (tag) {

          this.meta.removeTag('http-equiv=Content-Security-Policy');
          let content = tag.getAttribute('content');
          let str = 'connect-src ';
          let index = content.indexOf(str);
          content = content.slice(0, index + str.length) + "https://baseurl22/ https://baseurl23/ https://baseurl34/ " + content.slice(index + str.length);
            this.meta.updateTag({ 'http-equiv': 'Content-Security-Policy', content: content });
        } else {

          this.meta.addTag({ 'http-equiv': 'Content-Security-Policy', content: 'connect-src \'self\' https://baseurl1/ https://baseurl2/ https://baseurl3/;' });
        }

        if (i == 1) clearInterval(tim);
        i++;
    }, 1000);
```

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teecck

Comment: Didn't know about the Meta Component. I can't test it since I am currently on holidays, but it sounds very promising. Thank you. Will reward you when I am able to in 22 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of Content Security Policy this way, because assuming that browsers will honor CSP meta header this way (I doubt that), it is still better and more secure implantation of Content Security Policy is to use the HTTP response header instead. 
For a quick reference check [content-security-policy.com](https://content-security-policy.com/).

Comment: Thanks, but this solution was considered and is not an option in my case.

Comment: The thing is that browsers are going to dynamically understand that you have JS changing CSP meta header, which sounds buggy as most of the scripts and styles have been already loaded to the document. So you are telling the browser: hey browser! I'm a content script and here is the content policy!